# How to restrict second argument type on the first argument type?

Tags: typescript

In the tutorial [Extract parameter types from string literal types with TypeScript](https://lihautan.com/extract-parameters-type-from-string-literal-types-with-typescript/?utm_source=typescript-weekly.com&utm_campaign=typescript_weekly_193&utm_medium=email) there is an interesting problem without an answer.

```
function calculate(operation, data) {
    if (operation === 'add') {
        return data.addend_1 + data.addend_2;
    } else if (operation === 'divide') {
        return data.dividend / data.divisor;
    }
}
 
calculate('add', { addend_1: 1, addend_2: 2 });
calculate('divide', { dividend: 42, divisor: 7 });
```

How to define the type for a function like that?

Comment: Either functional overloads or discriminated union can get the typing done for you.

Comment: I know how to do this via function overloading. Can you please elaborate about the other solution?

Comment: You can do it with a destructured discriminated union type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N55P2N); do you want that written up as an answer?

Comment: Ingeniously! Yes please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to proceed is to represent the `operation` parameter as the *discriminant* property of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) that helps you narrow the apparent type of `data`.  Indeed, if you packaged `operation` and `data` in a single object instead of as separate parameters, this would be a straightforward task for a discriminated union:

```
interface AddData { addend_1: number; addend_2: number };
interface DivData { dividend: number; divisor: number };
type DiscU =
  { operation: "add", data: AddData } |
  { operation: "divide", data: DivData };

function calculateD(arg: DiscU) {
  if (arg.operation === 'add') {
    return arg.data.addend_1 + arg.data.addend_2;
  } else if (arg.operation === 'divide') {
    return arg.data.dividend / arg.data.divisor;
  } else throw new Error("invalid operation");
}

calculateD({ operation: 'add', data: { addend_1: 1, addend_2: 2 } });
calculateD({ operation: 'divide', data: { dividend: 42, divisor: 7 } });
```

TypeScript 4.6 introduced support for [destructured discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions), so you can represent the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to the function as a discriminated union which is destructured into separate parameters.  Like this:

```
function calculate(
  ...[operation, data]: ["add", AddData] | ["divide", DivData]
) {
  if (operation === 'add') {
    return data.addend_1 + data.addend_2;
  } else if (operation === 'divide') {
    return data.dividend / data.divisor;
  } else throw new Error("invalid operation")
}

calculate('add', { addend_1: 1, addend_2: 2 });
calculate('divide', { dividend: 42, divisor: 7 });
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN0BE5jsgb2TkwhHQH0BGALmRAFcBbAI2gG5jTyKAmOxq2jIAvuwBQoSLEQoswAG448hZOkXB0ZdAOZsondQuABnAPZRdQqKIlgAngAc5phAFVkAXnHJVZ51C4wGYgdABEJOhhADRquHB0GNjxosgAPj5+AUEh4UaaEDFxeHTySili4uIwDCAIYMEgyAhwADYIDK24EFgAFHBQAOalrm4AlISZwDDI-UMAdP7QOU2ea8gA5JEbEwSZvlAQYAxQTQOD8+jx85Ha1MgA1MQLV3g33JS8Er4iyBCtJhQ01m50W2QaIS86w2+S0O0mvgORxOZxe11h2mQAHpnhdXnBLhpzAZMr9-oDkGAABZQMwAd3oEAZAFEoLSoL0wqAFG1NMgloEISAwmMJCIqi12p1un0iAKVnQtpgNrF8XQiLceLRkFRYprPnReKkRKLxJKOl1ILL+eDGoqMSriglVBjyHQACy8VVEix0ADsxtN1Vq9UazTaFu6vUy81jAG15ULVfEALp0OMRTBFJLKOAp9LIDMYoplXMp8S7KYzXqJsNrTybbaVxHIQ7HU5O95aLWPTv6vjfVLkoHV2uQ+ubB3NxFtlGd13obHzn0kn5-AEoam0hkgJnIVnsznc3mLsfCsbicVmiPSyC9JXoR0aj7UOi6rjdg3II0miTm28QPeDqxEQC4el6agrv6oimkAA)